# Couldn't find hvm kernel for Ubuntu tree

Tags: ubuntu, centos, gpu, kvm

My server environment is centos7.3,I want to install kvm Ubuntu16.04 on it.My installation commands are as follows:

```
virt-install --name demo01 --ram 4096 \
--disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/demo01.img,size=90 \
--vcpus 2 --os-type linux --os-variant ubuntunatty \
--network bridge=br0 --graphics none --console pty,target_type=serial \ 
--location /workspace/ubuntu-16-server.iso \
--extra-args 'console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial' --host-device 04:00.0 \ 
--features kvm_hidden=on --machine q35 \
```

Then an error happened:

```
ERROR    Couldn't find hvm kernel for Ubuntu tree.
Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
If it was, you can restart your domain by running:
  virsh --connect qemu:///system start demo01
otherwise, please restart your installation.
```

Comment: The question had solved,the method is here: first：install python-virtinst Then：modify the "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtinst/OSDistro.py" like this: Change the line under else: condition in the init method, and change "i386" to "amd64"

Comment: But then I ran into new problems: ERROR unsupported configuration: IDE controllers are unsupported for this QEMU binary or machine type

Answer (score 1):

Tested solution for Ubuntu 20.04 Server with my extra args for [autoinstall](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-quickstart):

```
virt-install \
  --name=$VMNAME \
  --os-variant=ubuntu20.04 \
  --memory=2048 \
  --vcpus=1 \
  --network network=default \
  --disk=${IMG_PATH},cache=none,format=qcow2,bus=virtio \
  --location=/home/user/Downloads/ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso,kernel=casper/vmlinuz,initrd=casper/initrd \
  --extra-args "autoinstall ds=nocloud-net;s=http://192.168.122.1:3003/" \
  --noreboot
```

From `man virt-install`:

```
Additionally, --location can take 'kernel' and 'initrd' sub options. These paths relative to the specified location URL/ISO that allow selecting specific files for kernel/initrd
           within the install tree. This can be useful if virt-install/ libosinfo doesn't know where to find the kernel in the specified --location.

           For example, if you have an ISO that libosinfo doesn't know about called my-unknown.iso, with a kernel at 'kernel/fookernel' and initrd at 'kernel/fooinitrd', you can make this
           work with:

             --location my-unknown.iso,kernel=kernel/fookernel,initrd=kernel/fooinitrd
```